# Why is there such a big difference between LED brightness?

Tags: led

I have some LEDS, yellow and blue. Using the exact same battery, the blue LED runs significantly brighter than the yellow one - why is that? I have tested using multiple blue and multiple yellow and blue is consistently much brighter than the yellow under the same conditions.

You can see the difference here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the lumen or mcd ratings for the LED's you're comparing ?

Comment: Different technologies.

Comment: the yellow one actually looks brighter ... possibly a result of your camera and of the display I'm using

Answer (score 4):

Possible reasons

1. You seem to be powering the LEDs directly from a battery. Different LEDs have different resistance and different forward voltage drops. So, when you power directly from a battery different LEDs can draw different amount of current / power and output brightness is dependent on the input power.
2. The efficiency with which different colour LEDs convert input power to output light is different since the materials used and construction are different.
3. Our eye / camera sensor are sensitive to different colours at different amounts. (But blue would have had lower brightness then, I would think).